# Rabbit creature's facial features are not moving with the face

Tags: mesh, rigging

So I recently modeled a rabbit character and joined all the different pieces (like the eyes, arms, legs, etc.) and then rigged it, following [this tutorial.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cp1YRaTZBfw)

When I finished rigging, I went into pose mode and rotated the top bone. But the eyes, blush, and left ear didn't move with it. Only the face and the right ear rotated, as shown in the second picture below.

I have searched this up and read [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158481/why-are-the-eyes-and-face-not-moving-with-the-rest-of-head), but nothing helped. Here are some screenshots of my project:

**Picture 1:** Rigged character in the t-pose

[image: T-Pose]

**Picture 2:** Rotating the bone

[image: Facial Features not Moving with Face]

**Picture 3:** Rotating the spine (Front View)

[image: Front View]

**Picture 4:** Rotating the spine (Side View)

[image: Side View]

***Note:** Picture three and four are rotated differently so you can see the eyes blush, and nose aren't moving with it.*

I was wondering if I had to do some weight painting?

Comment: Are ears and jowls separated meshes? Or if not are they weighted to any bone? And yes if they are not, you should weight paint (or weight directly) them.

Comment: No they're one single mesh, because I joined them together. But how do I weight paint? I can only weight paint on the Nork mesh. Unless that's where you weight paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create your rig and set it as the parent of your model, you have to choose, how the weight for the bones are created. This determines, what parts of your model are affected by which bone.

If your model is one object with several parts, all you need to do is to add all the parts you want to be affected to the vertex group. You can find that under Properties -> Object Data Properties -> Vertex Groups. You can either go to edit mode and set all the verticies you want to be affected as part of the vertec gropu coresponding to your bone, or you can go to Wight paint mode and do int there. In weight paint mode, you can also see the poses. For more complex models you would use weight paint mode, but for your model, i think manualy adding all the verticies in edit mode might work fine.

If your model is split into several objects, you need to set the armature as parent for each object. Then you can adjust the vertex groups and weights the same way.

Comment: Hey @aky-her, thanks for the solution. Where is Properties -> Object Data Properties -> Vertex Groups? I can't seem to find that in the top panel or anywhere.

Comment: properties is one of the many panel types. If you did not change your layout, it is the one on the right, where you add modifiers, change render settings etc. Object Data Properties is the tab with green triangle on it (at least in the version of blender I am currently using)

Comment: Is this the one? [Blender Properties IMG](https://ibb.co/vLHmdnY)

Comment: yes, you can see the list of all the vertex groups there.

Comment: Okay...so do I weight paint the left ear, eyes, etc. all red? Or I just add more vertices in Edit Mode? Could you elaborate more please?

Comment: Yes. Blue = not affected by the bone, Red = affected by the bone. Most of the parts are affected by several bones, if you used the automatic weights, which might cause parts that are completely red not move completely with the bone, because another bone is holding them back. You can probably find some tutorials on weight painting, if you want more in depth information.

Comment: Well, it does [this](https://ibb.co/th842Yh) now. [This](https://ibb.co/TYJdNxD) is my weight painting on the character. [This](https://ibb.co/3h234fQ) is attempt two, and [this](https://ibb.co/F4whFNy) is attempt two's results.

Comment: That seems like you painted the weights to a wrong vertex group. Undo this (blender should create by deafult one save back backup. If you saved it twice or have this feature disabled, unparent the mesh and parent again with automatic weights). In the vertex group tab, select the one with the same name as the bone you want to alter and weight paint there. I can't see exactly what vertex group you painted, but from the pictures it seems it is the one controlling the right foot.

Comment: Thanks so much! It works now. In Vertex Groups, I selected Bone.001, which was my face bone, and then weight painted the facial features red, and did it inside and out, and it works!